# Objective-C - Locking rotation in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, autorotate, screen-rotation

My app uses only portrait mode. But ABPeoplePickerNavigationController supports landscape. Is it possible to have ABPeoplePickerNavigationController support only portrait mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass it and override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

```
// .h file
@interface MMABPeoplePickerPortraitOnlyNavigationController : ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
@end

// .m file
@implementation MMABPeoplePickerPortraitOnlyNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `AB` as the class prefix, that's reserved for the AddressBook framework classes.

Comment: Or `interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`. `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait()` is also true for PortraitUpsideDown, which is probably not what is intended.

Comment: @tc. Good point! I was working on an iPad app, so it was exactly what I intended. Readers while adapt this very short snippet to their needs.